# How to Check a Particular Element has a Value or another class inside it?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xlsx

How to check a particular Element has a value or inner elements?
here I have a list of Students, by using the name as search key displaying their results to richtextbox but here I have a problem where it comes to smith like students, I have one more table inside it as a list of marks, how to check and display
Do that particular element have value or elements? 
I am using C# and LINQ to retrieve the data.

```
<StudentDataset>
  <Student>
    <Name>Raj</Name>
    <TotalMarks>330</TotalMarks>
    <Year>2009+5</Year>
  </Student>

  <Student>
    <Name>Dennis</Name>
    <TotalMarks>514</TotalMarks>
    <Year>2009</Year>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Lisa</Name>
    <TotalMarks>510</TotalMarks>
    <Year>2011</Year>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Rahul</Name>
    <TotalMarks>490</TotalMarks>
    <Year>2019</Year>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Smith</Name>
    <TotalMarks>
      <IndividualScores>
        <Table Mode="SSC">
          <Item Marks="40" Result="10.6" />
          <Item Marks="100" Result="6.4" />
          <Item Marks="110" Result="5.7" />
          <Item Marks="120" Result="5" />
          <Item Marks="130" Result="4.3" />
          <Item Marks="140" Result="3.5" />
          <Item Marks="150" Result="2.8" />
        </Table>
        <Table Mode="Inter">
          <Item Marks="40" Result="8.8" />
          <Item Marks="50" Result="8.8" />
          <Item Marks="60" Result="8.8" />
          <Item Marks="70" Result="8.8" />
          <Item Marks="80" Result="8.8" />
        </Table>
      </IndividualScores>
    </TotalMarks>
    <Year>2013</Year>
  </Student>
  <Student >
        <Name>Jessy </Name>
        <TotalMarks><SchoolName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt; /.>
<English>88</English>
<Mathematics>90</mathematics>
<Science>98</science>
</SchoolName>
 </TotalMarks>
        <Year>2014</Year>
      </Student>

</StudentDataset>
```

C#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"filename");
IEnumerable<XElement> AllStudntElements = doc.Root.Elements();
var SelectDataByName = from element in AllStudntElements
where element.Element("Name").Value == SearchtItem
select element;
```

using for each loop it is working perfectly for every student but like smith how to check whether total marks have inner elements or not and how to display Marks and Results as a list for smith like students?
I have tried everything like **has children,hasAttribute** but nothing giving proper results?

For Jesse, I have XML schema, for Smith, I have a table 
How to know whether an Element has value or element or schema?

Very New to XML, what to use XmlReader and how to Crack this thing?
been trying from 4 days constantly on this but no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> students = Student.GetStudents(FILENAME);
            DataTable dt = Student.CreateTable(students);
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public int? intTotalMarks { get; set; }
        public List<TotalMarks> totalMarks { get; set; }

        public static List<Student> GetStudents(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            foreach (XElement xStudent in doc.Descendants("Student"))
            {
                Student student = new Student();
                students.Add(student);

                student.Name = (string)xStudent.Element("Name");
                student.Year = (string)xStudent.Element("Year");

                XElement xMarks = xStudent.Element("TotalMarks");
                if (xMarks.HasElements)
                {
                    foreach (XElement table in xStudent.Descendants("Table"))
                    {
                        TotalMarks totalMarks = new TotalMarks();
                        if (student.totalMarks == null) student.totalMarks = new List<TotalMarks>();
                        student.totalMarks.Add(totalMarks);

                        totalMarks.mode = (string)table.Attribute("Mode");
                        totalMarks.marks = table.Elements("Item").Select(x => new Mark()
                        {
                            mark = (int)x.Attribute("Marks"),
                            result = (decimal)x.Attribute("Result")
                        }).ToList();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    student.intTotalMarks = (int)xMarks;
                }
            }

            return students;
        }
        public static DataTable CreateTable(List<Student> students)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Mode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Mark", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(decimal));

            foreach(Student student in students)
            {
                if (student.totalMarks == null)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                            student.Name,
                            student.Year,
                            null,
                            student.intTotalMarks
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (TotalMarks totalMark in student.totalMarks)
                    {
                        foreach (Mark mark in totalMark.marks)
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                            student.Name,
                            student.Year,
                            totalMark.mode,
                            mark.mark,
                            mark.result
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
    public class TotalMarks
    {
        public string mode { get; set; }
        public List<Mark> marks { get; set; }

    }
    public class Mark
    {
        public int mark { get; set; }
        public decimal result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better?  Output is : List<Student> students

Comment: I mean how can i produce the Output for smith like student in this format?
``Name : Smith
SSC:
           Marks=40 Result=10.6 
           Marks=100 Result=6.4
           Marks=110 Result=5.7
           Marks=120 Result=5 
           Marks=130 Result=4.3 
           Marks=140 Result=3.5
           Marks=150 Result=2.8
        
         Inter:
           Marks=40 Result=8.8
           Marks=50 Result=8.8
          Marks=60 Result=8.8
          Marks=70 Result=8.8
Year:2013``

Comment: and for Jessy, There is A XmlSchema present 
how do I distinguish that total marks have the value or inner elements or schema 
am confused how to go about it?

Comment: Jessy should look like this : <Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;>Jessy</Name>

Comment: sir,
No i have at TotalMarks only
I wish i could send the image but i don't know how to keep images here

Comment: The namespaces are attributes, not innertext.

Comment: You have to edit your posting and add image to the posting, not the comments.

Comment: I have exact similar structure Sir, For it is not working

``XElement xMarks = xStudent.Element("TotalMarks");
                if (xMarks.HasElements)``
everytime if condition result is false
not going to inside it...

Comment: There are no elements when it is false.  What are the total marks for Raj?

Comment: In case of Jessy it is not working..i have updated the Jessy's exact values, it is of another case.. please look at Jessy values and tell me how to go about it

Comment: How to you want to output to look?  what you have for Jessy's marks is not very common with xml.   Having a different tag for each subject can have issues especially when the school name  tag exists.  Normally when you have different subject you would have a tag called mark and an attribute subject.

Comment: Sir @jdweng, Thanks for the help.. did it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Following the code you provided:

Select child "Table" elements of the Student using LINQ.

```
 var studentTables = from tables in SelectDataByName.Descendants("Table")
        select tables;

 if (studentTables.Any())
 {
       // do something
 }
```